# Sass Variable in CSS calc() function

Tags: css, sass, css-calc

I'm trying to use the `calc()` function in a Sass stylesheet, but I'm having some issues. Here's my code:

```
$body_padding: 50px

body
    padding-top: $body_padding
    height: calc(100% - $body_padding)
```

If I use the literal `50px` instead of my `body_padding` variable, I get exactly what I want. However, when I switch to the variable, this is the output:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: calc(100% - $body_padding);
}
```

How can I get Sass to recognize that it needs to replace the variable within the `calc` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usa a Variable in a Mixin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660985/usa-a-variable-in-a-mixin)

Comment: @user3705055 You do need calc as Sass can't calculate 100% - 50px as the units are different. This can only be calculated by the browser, once it knows how big the container is in order to convert 100% to px before adding the values. This is the exact reason why calc exists.

Comment: @cimmanon Well, the other way around now, since this question got way more popular.

Answer (score 3457, accepted):

[Interpolate](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation):

```
body
    height: calc(100% - #{$body_padding})
```

For this case, [border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Values) would also suffice:

```
body
    box-sizing: border-box
    height: 100%
    padding-top: $body_padding
```

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box;` would be the ideal way to go, in my opinion, of course.
In general, the box sizing model should make t

Comment: Many thanks! I was about to go the css route with `calc(100% - var(--body_padding))`

Comment: @leachim Sass interpolation is evaluated by the Sass compiler, not by the browser.

Comment: Even if it is OP's question, it’s almost always a bad idea to use interpolation with numbers. Interpolation returns unquoted strings that can’t be used for any further math, and it avoids Sass’s built-in safeguards to ensure that units are used correctly.
This case should be better handled with [sass' units](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/numbers#units)

Comment: Note interpolation is no longer needed since sass 1.40.0 per changelog entry `"Sass variables and functions can now be used in calc() expressions."`. So you can simple use `height: calc(100% - $body_padding)`.

Using the interpolation in `calc` is now actually discouraged by sass documentation at https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/calculations.

Comment: @Klofi I'd suggest you add this as a new answer, so that we can upvote it. One caveat that I've noticed: `calc()` in CSS variables / custom properties behaves differently and still requires interpolation. That is, `--my-custom-prop: calc(100vw + $myScssVariable)` will compile to `--my-custom-prop: calc(100vw + $myScssVariable)`, without `$myScssVariable` getting replaced with its value.

Answer (score 142):

To use `$variables` in `calc()` for any SCSS property:

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

SCSS:

```
$a: 4em;

div {
  height: calc(#{$a} + 7px);
  background: #e53b2c;
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I find this answer clearer. I don't do a lot of scss work, so this was "plainer" and easier for me to understand.

Comment: This is definitely a clearer answer than the accepted. 'Interpolate:' meant nothing to me.

Comment: @JacquesMathieu https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation  - If it doesn't mean anything to you and it's an answer with so many votes, probably you should understand what the fuss is about. Just my two cents...

Comment: @A. Chiesa sure, that defines interpolation. However the OP and I did not know of interpolation in SASS, otherwise this question would have never been asked. Thus just stating a word one may have never heard before without a definition or any pretense does not aid in creating an all inclusive answer. That link is certainly helpful though. Would have been nice to see that on the accepted answer.

Comment: I was stuck on this for more than 1 hour.

Comment: It's (now) easier to understand because this is written in the scss format vs sass format which is now for more common than it was when this was answered. (I actually don't know if it existed when this was asked, but if it didn't it was within roughly a year). I saw sass and immediately skipped over the accepted answer until I saw this scss answer.

Answer (score 59):

Even though its not directly related. But I found that the CALC code won't work if you do not put spaces properly.

So this did not work for me `calc(#{$a}+7px)`

But this worked `calc(#{$a} + 7px)`

Took me sometime to figure this out.

Comment: also an additional space after `calc` ist not allowed. `calc (#{$a} + 7px)` won't work out.

Comment: The person above used spaces correctly, so this doesn't really answer their question, but it answered mine. Thank you!

Comment: Yes this worked for me. I tried height:calc(100%-95px); (i.e without proper space. ) at first and it didn't work. But with proper spacing it worked without interpolation

Comment: care, this does not work in IE and Edge HTML

Answer (score 7):

I have tried this then i fixed my issue. It will calculate all media-breakpoint automatically by given rate (base-size/rate-size)

```
$base-size: 16;
$rate-size-xl: 24;

    // set default size for all cases;
    :root {
      --size: #{$base-size};
    }

    // if it's smaller then LG it will set size rate to 16/16;
    // example: if size set to 14px, it will be 14px * 16 / 16 = 14px
    @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
      :root {
        --size: #{$base-size};
      }
    }

    // if it is bigger then XL it will set size rate to 24/16;
    // example: if size set to 14px, it will be 14px * 24 / 16 = 21px
    @include media-breakpoint-up(xl) {
      :root {
        --size: #{$rate-size-xl};
      }
    }

@function size($px) {
   @return calc(#{$px} / $base-size * var(--size));
}

div {
  font-size: size(14px);
  width: size(150px);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a really simple solution using SASS/SCSS and a math formula style:

```
/* frame circle */
.container {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px; }

/* circle sectors */
.menu-frame-sector {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 10000;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  }

$sector_count: 8;
$sector_width: 360deg / $sector_count;

.sec0 {
    transform: rotate(0 * $sector_width) skew($sector_width);
    background-color: red; }
.sec1 {
    transform: rotate(1 * $sector_width) skew($sector_width);
    background-color: blue; }
.sec2 {
    transform: rotate(2 * $sector_width) skew($sector_width);
    background-color: red; }
.sec3 {
    transform: rotate(3 * $sector_width) skew($sector_width);
    background-color: blue; }
.sec4 {
    transform: rotate(4 * $sector_width) skew($sector_width);
    background-color: red; }
.sec5 {
    transform: rotate(5 * $sector_width) skew($sector_width);
    background-color: blue; }
.sec6 {
    transform: rotate(6 * $sector_width) skew($sector_width);
    background-color: red; }
.sec7 {
    transform: rotate(7 * $sector_width) skew($sector_width);
    background-color: blue; }
```

To conclude, I strongly suggest you to understand `transform-origin`, `rotate()` and `skew()`:

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/

Answer (score -7):

Try this:

```
@mixin heightBox($body_padding){
   height: calc(100% - $body_padding);
}

body{
   @include heightBox(100% - 25%);
   box-sizing: border-box
   padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: It won't work by the same reason as the code in the question.