# Css calc() function not working with sass file

Tags: css, sass, interpolation, css-variables

**Problem :**

- Correct use of calc function with sass file.

**Case :**

```
.class1  {
      max-width: calc(100% - #{$endWidth});
      min-width: $startWidth;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

.class2 {
      max-width: calc(100% - #{$startWidth});
      direction: rtl;
    }
```

**Tried Case :**

- I have verified few answers in stack overflow, and from one of the question answers inspired my question - [Stack Overflow Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982111/sass-variable-in-css-calc-function). The solutions aren't working for my scenario,
- Should I use mixin in sass to get it to work ?

Comment: @A.Sakkeer Did you read this question? OP has already tried that

Answer (score 0):

While **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** will indeed cause issues with SASS files by default, this can be avoided by using interpolation (which you are using correctly).

The only *possible* explanation(s) for your issue are:

- You do not have (or have it incorrectly defined)  **[SASS variables](https://marksheet.io/sass-variables.html):**`$startWidth` and `$endWidth`
- Rules with **[higher specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** are overriding your selectors
- You have cached old styles, hence clear your cache with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

**[Here's an example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLmc1q35/)** showcasing your above code working.