# SCSS mixin second param not compiled properly

Tags: scss-mixins

I am looking at the [mixin documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#arguments) and have created a simple mixin

```
@mixin mobile-pos($property, $offset) {
    // Fallback
    #{$property}: calc(100vh - $offset);

    // Better - for browsers that support custom css vars
    #{$property}: calc(var(--rvh) * 100 - $offset);
}
```

Here is how I'm using the mixin

```
#container-circles {
    bottom: unset;
    @include mobile-pos(top, 90px);
}
```

I checked the compiled CSS output

```
#container-circles {
  bottom: unset;
  top: calc(100vh - $offset);
  top: calc(var(--rvh) * 100 - $offset); }
```

Any idea why the second param is not getting compiled properly? I'm using     node-sass 4.11.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sass Variable in CSS calc() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982111/sass-variable-in-css-calc-function)

Comment: Found it, a lingering bug from 2013! `#{$offset}` was the "fix"

Answer (score 0):

Using `$variables` inside your `calc()` is like this

SCSS

```
    @mixin mobile-pos($property, $offset) {
      // Fallback
      #{$property}: calc(100vh - #{$offset});

      // Better - for browsers that support custom css vars
      #{$property}: calc(var(--rvh) * 100 - #{$offset});
    }
```