# Can't assign sass variable to css variable

Tags: sass, css-variables

This code doesn't work is Sass:

```
$color1: 

.App {
  --color1: $color1;
}
```

Why is this not valid syntax?  What is the proper syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sass Variable in CSS calc() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982111/sass-variable-in-css-calc-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This being invalid syntax is intended, the solution is to use:

```
$color1: 

.App {
  --color1: #{$color1};
}
```

The reason for this is discussed here: https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/2621

In short, css variables could potentially be a string that starts with a `$` character, and Sass did not want to block that syntax from working.  Given that `#{$someVar}` is not valid css syntax, it is functional and more explicit to have it be this way.