# Can I update SASS variables in Media Queries?

Tags: css, sass

Consider the following SASS code. I want to make sure that if the screen is above `1250px` then the `margin-top` should be `750px` and then it should change depending on size. However SASS does not allow me to update the variables inside the strings.

```
// Above 1250px
$pageTemplateMargin:750px;

// Below 1250px
@media screen and (max-width:1250px){
    $pageTemplateMargin:550px;
}

// Below 950px
@media screen and (max-width:950px){
    $pageTemplateMargin:450px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:850px){
    $pageTemplateMargin:150px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:750px){
    $pageTemplateMargin:250px;
}

// Render the correct code
.page-template {margin-top:$pageTemplateMargin}
```

Is there a better way for this, as it does not work and `page-template` stays at `750px`.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that `@media` queries trigger on the client side, where your sass variable is being processed server-side. My best bet would be to use a @mixin or something.

Comment: Why don't you put the margin declarations inside the media queries?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I agree with the accepted answer that it's better to use `maps` in this case but I want to point out a couple of things.

Variables can actually be updated inside of media queries. The problem is that a variable defined outside of a block is a **global** variable while one defined within a block is a **local** variable. You can let sass treat a variable within a block as a global variable using the **!global** keyword.

```
$pageTemplateMargin:750px;

@media screen and (max-width:1250px){
    $pageTemplateMargin: 550px !global;
}

.page-template {
  margin-top: $pageTemplateMargin //will use 550px instead of 750px
}
```

Just want to clarify that it is possible albeit it is not appropriate in this use case.

I also suggest using a `loop` for your code which will prove helpful especially if you add more screen widths and margin properties so you don't need to further write more media queries.

```
$breakpoints: (
  1200px: 10px,
  1000px: 15px,
  800px: 20px,
);

@each $width, $margin in $breakpoints {
  @media screen and (max-width: $width) {
    .element {
      margin-top: $margin;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer, upvoted, as a side note: you'll have to apply `px` in the `$width` part of your answer as well, since now the `max-width: $width` doesn't contain a unit.

Comment: I have also upvoted this and marked this as the correct answer as essentially it is the answer the to question despite maps maybe a better solution for others.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't (in this situation, as pointed out in the other answer).

I'd suggest using `mixins` to work with this:

```
@mixin pageTemplateMargin($px) {
    margin-top: $px
}

@media screen and (max-width:1250px) {
    .element { @include pageTemplateMargin(10px);}
}
@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
    .element { @include pageTemplateMargin(15px);}
}
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
    .element { @include pageTemplateMargin(20px);}
}
```

There's also a way of mapping through sass objects, such as:

```
$breakpoints: (
  1200: 10px,
  1000: 15px,
  800: 20px,
);

@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
    .element { margin-top: map-get($breakpoints, 1200);}
}
@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
    .element { margin-top: map-get($breakpoints, 1000);}
}
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
    .element { margin-top: map-get($breakpoints, 800);}
}
```

This would allow you to globally change the margin by adjusting 1 variable.

[Working codepen example](http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/LbWowB)

Comment: This looks pretty good. Unless it can be further reduced I will accept

Comment: There's a way of dividing this into objects which would make this approach more modular, let me google a bit further.

Comment: I've updated my code with a working example, @TheBlackBenzKid

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this then i fixed my issue. It will calculate all media-breakpoint automatically by given rate (base-size/rate-size)

```
$base-size: 16;
$rate-size-xl: 24;

    // set default size for all cases;
    :root {
      --size: #{$base-size};
    }

    // if it's smaller then LG it will set size rate to 16/16;
    // example: if size set to 14px, it will be 14px * 16 / 16 = 14px
    @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
      :root {
        --size: #{$base-size};
      }
    }

    // if it is bigger then XL it will set size rate to 24/16;
    // example: if size set to 14px, it will be 14px * 24 / 16 = 21px
    @include media-breakpoint-up(xl) {
      :root {
        --size: #{$rate-size-xl};
      }
    }

@function size($px) {
   @return calc(#{$px} / $base-size * var(--size));
}

div {
  font-size: size(14px);
  width: size(150px);
}
```