# Using media-queries to set variable values using Sass

Tags: css, sass

I have the following situation:

```
$var: mobiConfig;
@media (min-width: 750px) { 
 $var: deskConfig;
}
```

I am trying to change the sass variable within a media query and somehow it is always returning `deskConfig`

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I update SASS variables in Media Queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739695/can-i-update-sass-variables-in-media-queries)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an unusual instance of a common mistake: you are mixing *server-side* and *client-side* logic.

The `@media (min-width: 750px) { ... }` block is a directive which is passed onto the web browser to evaluate at run time, and conditionally apply rules. As you resize the browser window or viewport, the browser will continuously re-check this condition, and decide whether to apply the CSS rules it contains.

The `$var: deskConfig;` assignment, on the other hand, is a directive to the SASS/SCSS compiler. This runs over the entire file, processes it, and returns the result, which will probably be saved to disk, and served to every browser which visits. The compiler cannot know what size window someone will browse the site in.

The only thing SASS can do with `@media` queries is decide where to echo them in the resulting CSS. For instance, you can nest things "inside out", like `.foo { @media(min-width: 750px) { color: red; } }`, and SASS will generate the correct CSS `@media(min-width: 750px) { .foo { color: red; } }`.

I guess it would theoretically be possible for the compiler to detect that the assignment was in an `@media` block, and generate two versions of *every single rule which mentioned that variable*, so that `.foo { color: $var; }` automatically became `.foo { color: red; } @media(min-width: 750px) { .foo { color: red; } }`. But that would be incredibly complicated, and frankly rather confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you can achieve that desired behavior using css variables instead. You can define css variables for different media queries in one sass file, and then use those same variables to calculate different things in another file, provided that the file defining the variable, is imported before the file using the variable. Css variables are client side, so they will respond to the screen size change, unlike sass variables.

Here's how to change css variables on different screen sizes: https://www.w3schools.com/css//css3_variables_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

Sass variable scope is a little bid different than other implementations:

- Always set global variables and do not reset them throughout the
  stylesheet
- Make use of !default flag

For more info:
https://anotheruiguy.gitbooks.io/sassintherealworld_book-i/handy-tools/variable-scoping.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this then i fixed my issue. It will calculate all media-breakpoint automatically by given rate (base-size/rate-size)

Visit [Using media-queries to set variable values using Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49436927/using-media-queries-to-set-variable-values-using-sass/54188992#54188992)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$var: mobiConfig;
@media (min-width: 750px) { 
  $var: deskConfig !global;
  xxx: $var;                // = deskConfig 
  $var: mobiConfig !global;
}
yyy: $var;                  // = mobiConfig
```