# Setting value of a global variable in media query (revisited)

Tags: sass

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40741930/2725810) reply, I wrote:

```
$global-padding: 1em;
@media only screen and (max-width: 20em) {
    $global-padding: 0.5em !global;
}
```

For some reason, the padding is always 0.5em, not only when the screen is at most 20em wide. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#shadowing) the global variable gets overwritten during compile time, as soon as the nested rule is processed - and not if any condition is met. This is not a runtime feature. All SCSS is compile to plain old CSS during compile time.

> A variable declaration flagged as !global will *always* assign to the global scope.

So doing something like this:

```
$variable: foo;

.content {
  $variable: bar !global;
  value: $variable;
}

.sidebar {
  value: $variable;
}
```

will produce

```
.content {
  value: bar;
}

.sidebar {
  value: bar;
}
```

What you are trying to do can be done with css custom variables:

```
:root {
  --global-padding: 1em;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 20em) {
    --global-padding: 0.5em;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, why did they introduce SASS variables if CSS ones are more powerful?

Comment: Since I already use `$global-padding` all over the place, can I do something like `$global-padding: var(--global-padding)` or anything else of the sorts?

Comment: To answer your first question: 1. SASS variables and CSS custom variables are different things for different use-cases: the former is to allow having styling-wide constants that only needs to be changed in one place and allowing to parameterize functions and mixins. It is for compile time needs only and doesn't work during runtime. The latter is to allow dynamic changes during runtime, scoped by element nesting. It is for runtime needs only and doesn't work during compile time.
2. SASS is 14 years old and much older than the widespread browser support for CSS custom variables.

Comment: To answer your second question: yes you could do that `$global-padding: var(--global-padding);` but I don't recommend it. SASS will treat the value as a string and if all your usages only just read the value without making an arithmetic operation this will produce valid CSS. So this `.foo { padding: $global-padding; }` will become `.foo { padding: var(--global-padding); }`. But this is a setup that will sooner or later lead to an error when you or a colleague forgets the peculiar nature of this value. Use it like this `.foo { padding: $global-padding * 2; }` and it will produce invalid CSS.